# Combine functions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have 2 function that create balls. One create blue ball every 1 sec and the other creates red ball every 4 sec. I wish to add them togeteher. Because if game over the action is the same, and I actually do not need 2 funcs. So how can I combine the together in one function.

```
void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine(CreateBall());
    StartCoroutine(CreateBall_Red());
    gameOver = false;

}

IEnumerator CreateBall()
{
    while(true)
    {
        GameObject particlePop1 = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(ball);
        particlePop1.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), 6,0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        if (gameOver)
        {
            //restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
            //restart = true;
            break;
        }
    }


}

IEnumerator CreateBall_Red()
{
    while(true)
    {
        GameObject particlePop1 = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(ball_Red);
        particlePop1.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), 6,0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);

        if (gameOver)
        {

            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this change in that both functions

```
    if (gameOver)
    {
        //restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
        //restart = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);// For blue ball yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single function with two parameters:

```
IEnumerator CreateBall(GameObject prefab, float waitTime)
{
    while(true)
    {
        GameObject particlePop1 = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
        particlePop1.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), 6,0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        // Other stuff here
    }
}
```

and then simply call:

```
StartCoroutine(CreateBall(ball, 1));
StartCoroutine(CreateBall(ball_Red, 4));
```

Making it much more flexible!